# How can I add a format specifier to `format-time-string`?

Tags: emacs, elisp, format-string

I have the following function definition:

```
(defun nth (n)
  (format
   (concat
    "%d"
    (if (memq n '(11 12 13)) "th"
      (let ((last-digit (% n 10)))
        (case last-digit
          (1 "st")
          (2 "nd")
          (3 "rd")
          (otherwise "th"))))) n))
```

and I'd like to be able to use it in [`format-time-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html).
Normally, I would look at the source of the function, but this one is defined in the C source code.  (I would presume this precludes hooking something onto it, but I stand to be corrected.)

How can I add another format specifier (say, `%o`) that will apply `nth` to the appropriate argument?

Desired usage:

```
(format-time-string "%A, %B %o, %T (%z)" (seconds-to-time 1250553600))

=> "Monday, August 17th, 20:00:00 (-0400)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want to do. Stefan and Drew already gave some important remarks (don't overwrite `nth` and look at the info-files of emacs-lisp/advising functions).

```
(defun ordinal (n)
  "Special day of month format."
  (format
   (concat
    "%d"
    (if (memq n '(11 12 13)) "th"
      (let ((last-digit (% n 10)))
        (case last-digit
          (1 "st")
          (2 "nd")
          (3 "rd")
          (otherwise "th"))))) n))


(defadvice format-time-string (before ordinal activate)
  "Add ordinal to %d."
  (let ((day (nth 3 (decode-time (or time (current-time))))))
    (setq format-string
      (replace-regexp-in-string "%o"
                    (ordinal day)
                    format-string))))
```

Notes:

1. I did not handle the UNIVERSAL argument
2. The hack does not work when `format-time-string` is called from C (as you can read in the manual).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you're out of luck: format-time-string does not offer any way to do that.

You might be able to work around this by using something like:

```
(let ((ti (seconds-to-time 1250553600)))
 (format-time-string (concat "%A, %B " (my-nth (format-time-string "%d" ti)) ", %T (%z)") ti))
```

This said, I've always been told that "August 17th" is wrong: you're supposed to write "August 17" which is pronounced "August the seventheenth".

One more thing: `nth` is a predefined core function.  Better not overwrite it with your own completely different definition.

Comment: Completely forgot about the built-in `nth` - thanks for the reminder. You may be right about 'August 17th', but I believe 'the 17th of August' is correct in that morph.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Stefan said ("You're out of luck") --

`format-time-string` is a built-in, but you can *advise* built-ins too.  However, since the kind of surgery you want to do would dig into the bowels of the definition (which you cannot do), you would need to in fact *replace* the definition of `format-time-string` in the `defadvice`, i.e., not use `ad-do-it` at all.

In other words, one way or the other (`defun` or `defadvice`) you would need to completely redefine the function, in Lisp.  Which is about the same as saying "You're out of luck."